# Cocos2D iPhone - Object sent autorelease too many times?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have subclassed CCSprite and my class, named Cars, inits like this:

```
+(Cars *) carWithNumber:(int)number COLOR:(int)color SHAPE:(int)shape {
    return [[[Cars alloc] initWithNumber:number COLOR:color SHAPE:shape] autorelease];
}

-(id) initWithNumber:(int)number COLOR:(int)color SHAPE:(int)shape {

    self = [self init];

    if (self) {
        self.texture = [self createTextureWithNumber:number COLOR:color SHAPE:shape];
    }

    return self;
}
```

then I create a car using, for example, something like this:

```
Cars *oneCar = [Cars carWithNumber:2 COLOR:3 SHAPE:5];
[self addChild:oneCar];
```

It appears perfect, but if I analyze the code with Xcode, it points to this line

```
return [[[Cars alloc] initWithNumber:number COLOR:color SHAPE:shape] autorelease];
```

saying **object sent -autorelease too many times** ?????????

what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: That code looks fine to me.  Could you reduce it to a test case and put it online?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you've shown appears correct. Either this isn't the actual code, or there's some other relevant context not shown here. The code in your question is all correct.

Answer (score 0):

CCSprite is an autoreleased, you don't need to set your car to autorelease.

Comment: what do you mean by that? if I am allocating that, I have to autorelease. If I remove the autorelease from that line, Xcode complains about a possible memory leak there.